# Generate random between alphanumeric min and max in PHP

Tags: php, random

I am looking for an approach like `mt_rand` to generate a random value, but between two alphanumeric values instead of integers.

For example, `rand(g3j3j4k5, z9kDDkks8f8d)`.

I tried to convert the alphanumeric values to integers by `base_convert`. Beside the fact, it is somehow overkill, sometimes the integer is more than 15 digits, and thus not working in PHP rand functions.

**NOTE:** It is not about making a random string with given length. The value should between two given values, exactly like a random number between min and max integers.

Comment: How long would you like it? Just have a for loop and pick valid random characters

Comment: @EdHeal how? it's not about picking the characters only, as the length, min and max vary depending on the limiting values.

Comment: And what is the exact order of your alphanum values? like: `A-Za-z0-9` or `a-zA-Z0-9` ? And should be letters and numbers be mixed (e.g. `rand(0, "n")` should that be possible?)

Comment: @Rizier123 there is no order at all. The alphanumerics are treated as values (like their corresponding numeric values).

Comment: @All You mean ASCII representation? And if yes means you would also want `]` and so on if the range would be from `A` to `a`? Or only alphanum values?

Comment: @Rizier123 only basic alphanumeric, 0-9a-zA-Z.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I split `$min` and `$max` into an array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and loop through each character of both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

There I get the position of the character with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and return a random alphanum character in that particular range. If min is bigger than max I just return a random character from the entire range.

Code:

```
<?php

    function alphanum_rand($min = "", $max = ""){
        $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        $random = array_map(function($minC, $maxC)use($chars){
            if(($minKey = strpos($chars, $minC)) < ($maxKey = strpos($chars, $maxC)))
                return $chars[mt_rand($minKey, $maxKey)];
            else
                return $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars))];
        }, str_split($min), str_split($max));

        return implode("", $random);

    }

    echo alphanum_rand("g3j3j4k5", "z9kDDkks8f8d");

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try a simple PHP Function and define a random string alpha numeric and can also include special characters. For loop will do the magic for u :)

```
function RandomString($size)
{
    $chars    = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $string        = array();
    $alphaLength = strlen($chars) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $n      = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $string[] = $chars[$n];
    }
    return implode($string);
}
```

and simple call it with the size you need.

```
<?php
    echo RandomString(5); // Length of strings
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants, maybe you want to read the question again.